# Series Legendre Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, legendre-polynomials, legendre-functions

We have to prove

$$\ln \Big(\frac{x+1}{1-x}\Big)=\sum_{n≥0} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}P_n(x)$$

using the generatrix function of Legendre polynoms.

I don't know if it is useful, but $$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{1-2tx+x^2}dt=\frac{1}{x}\ln \Big(\frac{x+1}{1-x}\Big)$$

Comment: I can't confirm your last integral, even with online integration tools.

Comment: I have already changed

Comment: Can you tell us where this comes from?

Comment: The integral is solved by sustitution $y=1-2tx+x^2$

Comment: I know that, that's how I found your typo. But which book or whatever does the problem come from?

Comment: "Métodos matemáticos para científicos e ingenieros" Santos Bravo Yuste Universidad de Extremadura 2006 p.149 exercise 2.4.

Comment: Have you tried this: (i) write the GenFn  $=\sum P_n(t)x^n$; (ii) integrate both sides wrt $x$ from $0$ to $x$; (iii) substitute $t:=x$?

Answer (score 4):

The **Generating function** for Legendre polynomials is defined as
$$G(x,t):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n P_n(x) $$

Using harmonic functions, we can easily derive:

$$G(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2tx+t^2}} \quad \quad (1)$$

( *See More Here*: http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahdrb/MATHM242/OutlineCD2.pdf )

Taking into account $G$'s definition, one should observe that:

$$ \int_0^x G(x,t) dt = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}P_n(x) \quad \quad (2)$$

Also, from equation $(1)$:

$$\int_0^x G(x,t)dt=\int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2tx+t^2}} dt =\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{t^2-2xt+1}+t-x\right|\right)\Bigg|_0^x=$$
$$\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{1-x^2}\right|\right)-\ln\left(\left|1-x\right|\right)=\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt{1-x}\right|\right)-\ln\left(\left|1-x\right|\right)=\ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt{1-x}}{1-x}\right|\right)$$
$$=\ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}\right|\right)=\frac12 \ln \left(\left|\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right|\right) \quad \quad (3)$$

Now, from equations $(2),(3)$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}P_n(x)=\frac12 \ln \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$

assuming $(1+x)(1-x)>0$.

Comment: Well done, beat me to it by 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks. What about this $\frac12$ in front of the logarithm though?